# How to extract text between particular HTML tag in script

Tags: shell, unix

Given that I have some HTML in the form:

```xml
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="1" class="c">some other html stuff</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

How can I extract this with Unix script?

```
some other html stuff
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may checkout the [html-xml-utils](http://www.w3.org/Tools/HTML-XML-utils/) and the [`hxselect`](http://www.w3.org/Tools/HTML-XML-utils/man1/hxselect.html) command which allows you to extract elements that match a CSS selector:

```
hxselect '.c' < test.htm
```

This assumes that your input is a well-formed XML document. If it is not you might need to resort to regular expressions and the [possible consequences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) of that.

Comment: You might as well first pass the html code through [hxnormalize](http://www.w3.org/Tools/HTML-XML-utils/man1/hxnormalize.html), which tries to fix small errors in the code.

Comment: Am I right in assuming that option `-c` has been forgotten?

Answer (score 1):

For simple uses, you can use Ex editor, for example:

```
$ ex +'/<div/norm vity' +'%d|pu 0|%p' -scq! file.html
some other html stuff
```

where it finds `div` tag, then selecting inner HTML tag (`vit`) of found tag, yank it (`y`) in order to replace the buffer with it (`%delete`, `put 0`), then print it (`%print`), and quit (`-cq!`).

Other example with demo URL:

```
$ ex +'/<div/norm vity' +'%d|pu 0|%p' -Nscq! http://example.com/
```

The advantage is that `ex` is a standard Unix editor available in most Linux/Unix distributions.

See also:

- [How to jump between matching HTML/XML tags?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/780/467) at Vim SE
- [How to remove inner content of html tag conditionally?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/3299/467) at Vim SE